# How to make KineticJS canvas stage responsive

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

When adding a canvas element to a page I want the canvas and its contents to scale down as the browser window scales down.

There seem to be several questions asked about this here and with each one I haven't quite found the answer I was looking for. I seem to have something that works and thought I would post it for others to shoot down or improve upon.

In this example I have a page which is 1000px wide at max width. The canvas element is only 800px wide at max width.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    background-color: #888888;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var maxStageWidth = 800;
var maxStageHeight = 500;
var maxPageWidth = 1000;

// Check to see if window is less than desired width and calls sizing functions
function setStageWidth() {
    if (window.innerWidth < maxPageWidth) {

        resizeStage();

    } else {

        maxStageSize();

    };
};

// Sets scale and dimensions of stage in relation to window size
function resizeStage() {

    var scalePercentage = window.innerWidth / maxPageWidth;

    stage.setAttr('scaleX', scalePercentage);
    stage.setAttr('scaleY', scalePercentage);
    stage.setAttr('width', maxStageWidth * scalePercentage);
    stage.setAttr('height', maxStageHeight * scalePercentage);
    stage.draw();
};

//Sets scale and dimensions of stage to max settings
function maxStageSize() {
    stage.setAttr('scaleX', 1);
    stage.setAttr('scaleY', 1);
    stage.setAttr('width', maxStageWidth);
    stage.setAttr('height', maxStageHeight);
    stage.draw();
};

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: maxStageWidth,
    height: maxStageHeight,
    scaleX: 1
});

var circles = new Kinetic.Layer();

var circleRed = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 100,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: 'red'
});

var circleBlue = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2 + 120,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2 + 175,
    radius: 50,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: 'blue'
});

var circleOrange = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 175,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2 + 100,
    radius: 75,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: 'orange'
});

circles.add(circleRed);
circles.add(circleBlue);
circles.add(circleOrange);

stage.add(circles);

// On load we set stage size based on window size
setStageWidth();

// On window resize we resize the stage size
window.addEventListener('resize', setStageWidth);
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your functions. Can you explain more of what you're trying to acheive? Shouldn't your Max page width and max stage width be the same number?

Your functions are doing two things: scaling and resizing, but you are focusing on the scale based on the horizontal change. Try changing it to a diagonal scaling factor or scale vertical and horizontal separately.

```
// Sets scale and dimensions of stage in relation to window size
function resizeStage() {

   var horizScalePercentage = window.innerWidth / maxPageWidth; 
   var vertiScalePercentage = window.innerHeight/ maxPageHeight; 

   stage.setAttr('scaleX', horizScalePercentage );
   stage.setAttr('scaleY', vertiScalePercentage );
   stage.setAttr('width', maxStageWidth * horizScalePercentage );
   stage.setAttr('height', maxStageHeight * vertiScalePercentage );
   stage.draw();
};

//Sets scale and dimensions of stage to max settings
function maxStageSize() {
    stage.setAttr('scaleX', 1);
    stage.setAttr('scaleY', 1);
    stage.setAttr('width', maxStageWidth);
    stage.setAttr('height', maxStageHeight);
    stage.draw();
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8cw7J/1/ Check this fiddle

Comment: My thought was to have a page in which the canvas was only component of the document and there would be content on one side of it, thus my arbitrary 80% canvas / 100% page width. The functions do seem to work for it, but being a canvas newb I thought would put this out there to see if there was a "right" or more efficient way to do this.

Comment: In your fiddle its responsive but it stretches the content within!! any work around for that?

Comment: Yes, it is meant to stretch the content. If you don't want stretching, remove the lines which say setAttr and contain "scaleX" and "scaleY"